# How to write url from company Area to main Dashboard login?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am new please Help me in this url from company Area to main Dashboard login.
I am logging out the company and redirects it to dashboard login page, this is the URL I am using :

`window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Dashboard", "LoginPage", new { area = "" })";`

This is URL after redirect :

```
https://localhost:44345/Company/Dashboard/LoginPage
```

This is what I want:

```
https://localhost:44345/Dashboard/LoginPage
```

Company is my area.

Comment: If you got to `https://localhost:44345/Dashboard/LoginPage` directly (browser bar navigation) does it also redirect you to `https://localhost:44345/Company/Dashboard/LoginPage` automatically ?

Comment: when I click on the logout URL it redirects to https://localhost:44345/Company/Dashboard/LoginPage instead of https://localhost:44345/Dashboard/LoginPage in the nav bar

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to get in MVC 5 :

```
https://localhost:44345/Dashboard/LoginPage
```

is :

```
@Url.Action("LoginPage", "Dashboard", new { area = "" })
```

if it's not working, please check default route in your folder: `App_Start`
file: `RouteConfig.cs`